# re-enable mouse scroll inertia in Sierra

Tags: macos

In previous versions of macOS (OSX), when I scrolled fast, the page woule keep sliding a bit, as if there was some inertia keeping it moving. This seems to have been disabled in Sierra, and I can't find the setting to re-enable it.

Comment: See [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/254532/88313).  There's a lot of mouse issues on Sierra.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link. I've found the issue, but I'll bookmark that in case anything else comes up.

Answer (score 1):

I found the setting in System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Trackpad Options.

It was enabled, and disabling it and re-enabling fixed the issue for me.
[image]

Comment: The option for the mouse has been removed though.